# Invalid conversion from 'int' to 'time_t*' AND another error

Tags: c++, random, compiler-errors

I got the following errors:

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'time_t*'
>
> error:    initializing argument 1 of 'time_t time(time_t*)'

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char Grid[5][5];
Grid[0][0] = 'P';
Grid[0][1] = '-';
Grid[0][2] = '-';
Grid[0][3] = '-';
Grid[0][4] = '-';
Grid[1][0] = '-';
Grid[1][1] = 'T';
Grid[1][2] = '-';
Grid[1][3] = '-';
Grid[1][4] = '-';
Grid[2][0] = '-';
Grid[2][1] = '-';
Grid[2][2] = '-';
Grid[2][3] = '-';
Grid[2][4] = '-';
Grid[3][0] = '-';
Grid[3][1] = '-';
Grid[3][2] = '-';
Grid[3][3] = 'T';
Grid[3][4] = '-';
Grid[4][0] = '-';
Grid[4][1] = '-';
Grid[4][2] = '-';
Grid[4][3] = '-';
Grid[4][4] = 'X';
cout<<"P = Player (you)"<<endl<<
      "T = Trap (ouch!)"<<endl<<
      "X = Treasure (X marks the spot)"<<endl<<
      "Tell P where to go by using the commands 'right','left','up','down'."<<endl<<endl;
string command;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int a;
int b;
srand(time(a));
srand(time(b));
int enemy1 = rand()%4;
do
{
    cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<Grid[0][0]<<Grid[0][1]<<Grid[0][2]<<Grid[0][3]<<Grid[0][4]<<endl<<
      Grid[1][0]<<Grid[1][1]<<Grid[1][2]<<Grid[1][3]<<Grid[1][4]<<endl<<
      Grid[2][0]<<Grid[2][1]<<Grid[2][2]<<Grid[2][3]<<Grid[2][4]<<endl<<
      Grid[3][0]<<Grid[3][1]<<Grid[3][2]<<Grid[3][3]<<Grid[3][4]<<endl<<
      Grid[4][0]<<Grid[4][1]<<Grid[4][2]<<Grid[4][3]<<Grid[4][4]<<endl;
    cout<<"Your command: ";
    cin>>command;
    cout<<endl;
    if(command=="up")
    {
        Grid[(x-1)][y] = 'P';
        x--;
        Grid[(x+1)][y] = '-';
    }
    if(command=="down")
    {
        Grid[(x+1)][y] = 'P';
        x++;
        Grid[(x-1)][y] = '-';
    }
    if(command=="right")
    {
        Grid[x][(y+1)] = 'P';
        y++;
        Grid[x][(y-1)] = '-';
    }
    if(command=="left")
    {
        Grid[x][(y-1)] = 'P';
        y--;
        Grid[x][(y+1)] = '-';
    }
    if(x==4 && y==4)
    {
        if(command=="down")
        {
            Grid[4][4] = 'P';
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<Grid[0][0]<<Grid[0][1]<<Grid[0][2]<<Grid[0][3]<<Grid[0][4]<<endl<<
            Grid[1][0]<<Grid[1][1]<<Grid[1][2]<<Grid[1][3]<<Grid[1][4]<<endl<<
            Grid[2][0]<<Grid[2][1]<<Grid[2][2]<<Grid[2][3]<<Grid[2][4]<<endl<<
            Grid[3][0]<<Grid[3][1]<<Grid[3][2]<<Grid[3][3]<<Grid[3][4]<<endl<<
            Grid[4][0]<<Grid[4][1]<<Grid[4][2]<<Grid[4][3]<<Grid[4][4]<<endl;
            cout<<"You win!"<<endl;
        }
        if(command=="right")
        {
            Grid[4][4] = 'P';
            cout<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl<<endl;
            cout<<Grid[0][0]<<Grid[0][1]<<Grid[0][2]<<Grid[0][3]<<Grid[0][4]<<endl<<
            Grid[1][0]<<Grid[1][1]<<Grid[1][2]<<Grid[1][3]<<Grid[1][4]<<endl<<
            Grid[2][0]<<Grid[2][1]<<Grid[2][2]<<Grid[2][3]<<Grid[2][4]<<endl<<
            Grid[3][0]<<Grid[3][1]<<Grid[3][2]<<Grid[3][3]<<Grid[3][4]<<endl<<
            Grid[4][0]<<Grid[4][1]<<Grid[4][2]<<Grid[4][3]<<Grid[4][4]<<endl;
            cout<<"You win!"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
while(Grid[4][4] != 'P');
return 0;
}
```

The line I got these errors on was line 45 (and 46 but it's the same errors).
The following code is on line 45:

```
srand(time(a));
```

Comment: Please in the future reduce your code *to the essential* necessary to reproduce the problem and leave off everything that’s irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use `time` this way? The function is declared as so:

```
time_t time ( time_t * timer )
```

Passing it an `int` instead of a pointer to a `time_t` is definitively an error, and the compiler correctly complains.

Assuming all you need is a seed for the `srand`, just use `time(NULL)`. If you do need that value set in the argument, make `a` and `b` variables of type `time_t`, and use `time(&a)`. For further information about `time`, [read this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/).

Comment: @Bob, by "that", do you mean `srand(time(NULL));`? You can also use `srand(time(&a));` as long as `a` is of type `time_t`, but since you don't seem to be using `a` after the `srand`, you can probably just use the `NULL` call and get rid of `a` and `b` altogether.

Answer (score 2):

I'm almost sure you want to call `srand(time(NULL))` and do it only once. It sets a seed for a pseudo-random number generator and using actual time is most common case (it's different every time you run your application, hence the sequence of generated numbers is). To get the actual time you call `time(NULL)`; if you want the time value to be stored in the specific time_t variable, you can pass its pointer instead of NULL.

This code:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

and this code:

```
time_t now;
time(&now);
srand(now);
```

and even this code:

```
time_t now;
srand(time(&now));
```

are equivalent (for srand purposes).

Comment: Good point. I was focusing on the call to `srand` itself, and have missed the second call's redundancy. +1.